# How to add jquery photo gallery or slider in .asp page

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp-classic, photo-gallery

Here's my gallery tab that i want to have a jquery photo gallery or slide. I already downloaded a jquery photo gallery script but my big trouble is i don't know where to put the code on the page. Please help me. 
[image]

Here's my gallery.asp code: (Please tell me where to put the photo gallery jquery code)

```
  <% intSectionId = 103 %>
<!--#include file ="include/inc_header.asp"-->
<!--#include file ="include/functions_default.asp"-->
<body>
    <div id="art-page-background-gradient"></div>
    <div id="art-main">
        <div class="art-Sheet">
            <div class="art-Sheet-tl"></div>
            <div class="art-Sheet-tr"></div>
            <div class="art-Sheet-bl"></div>
            <div class="art-Sheet-br"></div>
            <div class="art-Sheet-tc"></div>
            <div class="art-Sheet-bc"></div>
            <div class="art-Sheet-cl"></div>
            <div class="art-Sheet-cr"></div>
            <div class="art-Sheet-cc"></div>
            <div class="art-Sheet-body">
                <!-- start header2 section -->
                <!--#include file ="include/inc_header2.asp"-->
                <!-- end header2 section -->
                <!-- start navigation section -->
                <!--#include file ="include/inc_navigation.asp"-->
                <!-- end navigation section -->
                <!-- start main content section -->
                <div class="art-contentLayout">
                    <div class="art-content">
                        <div class="art-Post">
                            <div class="art-Post-body">
                                 <!-- start inner content section -->
                                <div class="art-Post-inner">
                                        <h2 class="art-PostHeader">
                                            Gallery</h2>
                                        <div class="art-PostContent">
                                        <div style="float:right;margin:0px 5px 5px 5px"></div>                                        
                                        <p>&nbsp;</p>
                                        <p>&nbsp;</p>
                                        <p>&nbsp;</p>
                                        <p>&nbsp;</p>
                                        <div style="padding:0px 60px 0px 60px;">
                                        <p>&nbsp;</p>
                                        </div>
                                            <div style="padding:0px 60px 0px 60px;">
                                        <p align="right">&nbsp;</p>
                                        </div>

                                          </div>
                                        <div class="cleared"></div>
                                <!-- end inner content section -->
                                </div>
                                <div class="cleared"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                <!-- end main content section -->
                <!-- start sidebar section -->
                <!--#include file ="include/inc_sidebar.asp"-->
                <!-- end sidebar section -->
                <!-- start footer section -->
                <!--#include file ="include/inc_footer.asp"-->  
                <!-- end footer section -->
                </div>
                <div class="cleared"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="cleared"></div>
        <p class="art-page-footer"></p>
    </div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you used jcarousal sorgalla.com/jcarousel see the examples you will get your answer

Answer (score 0):

it depends on your css, and on the particular jquery widget, but i think you should try right after:

```
<div class="art-PostContent">
```